# Espresso Idling Resource not working with recyler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso, android-testing

I have developed an app in which i have to test the recyler view and certain actions after clicking it. For which i have written test cases But the tests are failing because the espresso is not waiting till the recycler view is loaded. I have implemented the SimpleIdlingResource, though its not useful. Pls provide me some ideas on fixing the same.

The following is the error am getting while running the test cases.

```
Testing started at 5:18 PM ...

02/24 17:18:01: Launching BakingActivityEspres... $ adb push /Users/nizamudeenms/Documents/BakingApp/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.example.nizam.bakingapp $ adb shell pm install -t
-r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.nizam.bakingapp" Success


No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of /Users/nizamudeenms/Documents/BakingApp/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk $ adb shell am force-stop com.example.nizam.bakingapp.test Running tests

$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class com.example.nizam.bakingapp.BakingActivityEspressoTest com.example.nizam.bakingapp.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner Client not ready yet.. Started running tests

android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'is displayed on the screen to the user' doesn't match the selected view. Expected: is displayed on the screen to the user Got: "RecyclerView{id=2131230869, res-name=recycler_view, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=1080, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}"

at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method) at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1536) at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92) at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56) at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184) at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158) at com.example.nizam.bakingapp.BakingActivityEspressoTest.ensureRecyclerViewExists(BakingActivityEspressoTest.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55) at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270) at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59) at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262) at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2081) Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 'is displayed on the screen to the user' doesn't match the selected view. Expected: is displayed on the screen to the user Got: "RecyclerView{id=2131230869, res-name=recycler_view, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=1080, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}"

at android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.assertThat(ViewMatchers.java:1053) at android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions$2.check(ViewAssertions.java:89) at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.run(ViewInteraction.java:170) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)


android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'actionOnItemAtPosition performing ViewAction: single click on item at position: 1' on view 'with id: com.example.nizam.bakingapp:id/recycler_view'. at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83) at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:80) at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56) at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184) at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115) at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87) at com.example.nizam.bakingapp.BakingActivityEspressoTest.ensureStepsListExists(BakingActivityEspressoTest.java:55) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55) at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270) at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59) at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262) at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2081) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints: (is assignable from class: class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView and is displayed on the screen to the user) Target view: "RecyclerView{id=2131230869, res-name=recycler_view, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=1080, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}" at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:138) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)


android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'actionOnItemAtPosition performing ViewAction: single click on item at position: 1' on view 'with id: com.example.nizam.bakingapp:id/recycler_view'. at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83) at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:80) at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56) at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184) at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115) at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87) at com.example.nizam.bakingapp.BakingActivityEspressoTest.ensureIngredientListExists(BakingActivityEspressoTest.java:61) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55) at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270) at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59) at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262) at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2081) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints: (is assignable from class: class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView and is displayed on the screen to the user) Target view: "RecyclerView{id=2131230869, res-name=recycler_view, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=1080, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=0}" at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:138) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)


android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'with id: com.example.nizam.bakingapp:id/steps_list_recycler_view'. at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83) at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:80) at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56) at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184) at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115) at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87) at android.support.test.espresso.DataInteraction.load(DataInteraction.java:151) at android.support.test.espresso.DataInteraction.perform(DataInteraction.java:128) at com.example.nizam.bakingapp.BakingActivityEspressoTest.checkPlayerViewIsVisible_RecipeDetailActivity1(BakingActivityEspressoTest.java:68) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26) at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27) at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55) at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270) at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128) at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115) at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59) at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262) at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2081) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints: (is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView and is displayed on the screen to the user) Target view: "RecyclerView{id=2131230916, res-name=steps_list_recycler_view, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1028, height=742, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=7}" at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:138) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:172) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6637) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Tests ran to completion.
```

Git hub Link :

https://github.com/nizamudeenms/BakingApp/commits/master

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem?

Comment: @user1055395 Yes, Please find the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I rectified the error by developing a class called Message delayer.

```
class MessageDelayer {

    private static final int DELAY_MILLIS = 5000;

    interface DelayerCallback {
        void onDone(String text);
    }

    /**
     * Takes a String and returns it after {@link #DELAY_MILLIS} via a {@link DelayerCallback}.
     * @param message the String that will be returned via the callback
     * @param callback used to notify the caller asynchronously
     */
    static void processMessage(final String message, final DelayerCallback callback,
                               @Nullable final SimpleIdlingResource idlingResource) {
        // The IdlingResource is null in production.
        if (idlingResource != null) {
            idlingResource.setIdleState(false);
        }

        // Delay the execution, return message via callback.
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (callback != null) {
                    callback.onDone(message);
                    if (idlingResource != null) {
                        idlingResource.setIdleState(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, DELAY_MILLIS);

    }
}
```

The DELAY_MILLIS is the amount of time to wait till next test case is started. Simple idling resource can be used as follows.

1. Define SimpleIdlingResource in the Activity.

> ```
> @Nullable
> private SimpleIdlingResource mIdlingResource;
> ```

2. Implement the method getIdlingResource() in same activity and create instance.

> ```
>   @VisibleForTesting
>     @NonNull
>     public IdlingResource getIdlingResource() {
>         if (mIdlingResource == null) {
>             mIdlingResource = new SimpleIdlingResource();
>         }
>         return mIdlingResource;
>     }
> ```

3. call the getIdlingResource() method and setIdleState to false from where the test should start waiting.

> ```
> getIdlingResource();  
> if (mIdlingResource != null){
>      mIdlingResource.setIdleState(false);
> }
> ```

4. Finally call the processMessage() method.

> ```
> final String text = "Sample Text";
>  MessageDelayer.processMessage(text, this, mIdlingResource);
> ```

We have to write separate test cases for Activity Test and Intent Test in different class files.
Dont forget to register and unregister the resources in the espresso testing methods as follows.

**Activity Test**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class BakingActivityEspressoTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<BakingActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(BakingActivity.class);

    private IdlingResource mIdlingResource;

    @Before
    public void registerIdlingResource() {
        mIdlingResource = mActivityRule.getActivity().getIdlingResource();
        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
    }

    @Test
    public void ensureRecyclerViewExists() {
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.recycler_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(1));
        onView(withText("Brownies")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }

    @Test
    public void checkPlayerViewIsVisible_RecipeDetailActivity1() {
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.recycler_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.steps_list_recycler_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
        onView(withId(R.id.exo_player_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }

    @After
    public void unregisterIdlingResource() {
        if (mIdlingResource != null) {
            Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
        }
    }
}
```

**Intent Test**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class BakingIntentEspressoTest {
    private IdlingResource mIdlingResource;

    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<BakingActivity> intentsTestRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(
            BakingActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void registerIdlingResource() {
        mIdlingResource = intentsTestRule.getActivity().getIdlingResource();
        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
        // Stub all external intents
        intending(not(isInternal())).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null));
    }

    @Test
    public void checkBakingRecyclerViewItemHasIntentWithAKey() {
        onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(1, click()));
        intended(hasExtraWithKey("bakingId"));
    }

    @After
    public void unregisterIdlingResource() {
        if (mIdlingResource != null) {
            Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
        }
    }
}
```

For further clarifications fork my github repo and check.